# Proving a parametrized curve is orthogonal to its derivative

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $\alpha:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a parametrized curve, with $\alpha'(t)\neq 0$ for all $t\in I$.
>
> Show that $|\alpha(t)|\neq 0 \iff \alpha(t)$ is orthogonal to $\alpha'(t)$ for all $t\in I$

$|\alpha(t)|=k (\neq 0)\iff \alpha(t)\neq 0\iff  \alpha'(t)\neq 0\iff  \alpha(t)\cdot  \alpha'(t)\neq 0$

is it valid?

Comment: In the question it is written that $|\alpha(t)|$ is a nonzero constant

Comment: No, it is written in your title  "fixed vector" (here is a fixed vector: $(5,3)$): there is no norm ! You should say that the "norm of $\alpha(t)$" is constant.

Comment: Why is $\alpha(t)\neq0 \Longleftrightarrow \alpha'(t)\neq0$ valid?

Comment: @md2perpe you are right $\alpha(t)=cost,sint$ at $t=0$

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$.

If $\|\alpha(t)\|$ is a constant $C$, then

$$\|\alpha(t)\|^2=\alpha(t)^2=x(t)^2+y(t)^2+z(t)^2=C^2.$$

Differentiating (1) gives the dot product:

$$2\alpha(t).\alpha'(t)=2x(t)x'(t)+2y(t)y'(t)+2z(t)z'(t)=(C^2)'=0$$

which means that $\alpha(t) \perp \alpha'(t)$ for all $t$.

Comment: intuitively, the curve described by $\alpha$ is traced on the sphere with center $O$ and radius $C$. It is intuitive that the speed vector of this curve is tangent to the sphere at the current point $\alpha(t)$.

Comment: Am afraid the normal vector is nowhere fixed in direction

Comment: 1. is it correct to say that you took $\sqrt{<\alpha(t),\alpha(t)>}=C$
and then ${<\alpha(t),\alpha(t)>}=C^2$ and differentiating it  ${<\frac{d}{dt}\alpha(t),\alpha(t)>}=C^2$?

2. So the speed vector is tangent to the trace and orthogonal to the parameterized curve?

Comment: Yes, essentially so. Second one  can be  $\beta(t) $ coplanar

Answer (score 1):

$$( x= f(t), y= g(t), z=c), $$

where $(f,g)$ are arbitrary functions and $c$ is a const. Their tangent is orthogonal to z-axis.

Comment: I don't think it is what the OP means...

Comment: @JeanMarie Narasimham's answer sets the stage for [your answer below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2253491/37058) by showing that without further assumptions, the statement that the OP wished to prove does not necessarily hold.